# MarkLogic Node.js. How to specify return properties in result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, marklogic, rest

How can I specify returned fields in my query so that I can avoid large data in my response. For example I have a json like this and I want only summary in response:

```json
{
   foo:"bar",
   summary:"my summary",
   other:[
      {key: "random thing", value: 5},
      {key: "another random", value: 3}
   ]
}
```

```js
var ml = require('marklogic');
var conn = require('./config.js').connection;
var db = ml.createDatabaseClient(conn);
var qb = ml.queryBuilder;

db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.collection('test')   
  )
  .withOptions({metrics: true})
).result()
.then(function(docs) {
  console.log('This search found: ' + JSON.stringify(docs[1]));
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('something went wrong: ' + error);
});
```

Comment: MarkLogic has a few different ways of running queries. Please add some detail to your question that shows how you are making the calls to MarkLogic.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options:

- Install a transform and transform the documents on the server; see:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_79910

- Specify paths to extract from the documents:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_17648

Hoping that helps,